# 'code .' command to open vscode from git bash not working anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I was getting used to opening VScode from git bash using 'code .' command. However, after creating some new git repo's and setting them up with a remote from github this command suddenly doesn't work anymore. The error message I get is:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Library\c\Users\[NAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1010:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:858:27)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Apparently I somehow concatenated a UNIX style path to a Windows style path, but I don't know how I did it. More importantly, how I can resolve this error. Running 'code.cmd .' works, but without the extension .cmd it doesn't anymore. In windows PS and cmd 'code .' runs fine without the additional '.cmd'.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same error.

Cause : You are trying to run the Node.js script from a location inside your Anaconda installation directory. This might cause issues because Anaconda and Node.js may have different environments and dependencies.

Solution : for this is I was in my 'base' environment just deactivate it will work fine or else use any other venv.

steps I followed are below

> conda deactivate

Then move in required directory where your project is then do

> code .

it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion. I have tried your solution and it appears it only works well for one specific conda env I made for this project. So it doesn't work in base environment. I would like it to work in conda base env though, do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I think we cannot do that, since its creating conflicts as mentioned before